# Can't call methods on object passed from template

Tags: angular

I modified one of the original examples on angular2 website to demonstrate the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sz4i2JITJyNznIyZsNRM?p=preview

I am passing a Hero object in the click event of the tiles and trying to call the .speak()  method of that object, but then an error is thrown - hero.speak is not a function.

```
  sayHeroName(hero: Hero) {
    hero.speak();
  }
```

While debugging this I found that there are no methods on that object, only its properties

So, my question is if it is possible to access object's methods like this and what's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Heroes in this list `public heroes: Hero[] = [];` inside the `app/dashboard.component.ts` are populated from `app/mock-heroes.ts` via the `app/hero.service.ts`.

When you look inside the `app/mock-heroes.ts` you will notice that they are just plain JS Objects that's why there is no `speak()` method on them.

To achieve your goal you will need to modify the `app/mock-heroes.ts` to return a list of `new Hero();` instead and modify the `app/Hero.ts` constructor to accept the `id` and `name` as a parameter.

OR

Modify the `app/hero.service.ts` to create the list of `new Hero();` object instances based on the list from `app/mock-heroes.ts`.

I hope this will nudge you in the right direction.